# React Native: How to make a push notification with custom content?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

I'm using OneSignal in my React Native project, and want to create something similar to this image, where there's a timer ticking down, and buttons that trigger events in the app itself:

[image]

I have no idea how to approach customizing the UI like this, and haven't had any luck looking for guides or tutorials. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about adding buttons inside your push notifications, you need to add Action Buttons with your notification. Please check this [page](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/action-buttons) for complete details